# Commit current dirty cell on clicking File/Save or Ctrl+S in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have:

1. `MenuStrip` that has File>Save that saves `DataGridView` values to a database
2. `DataGridView` that has columns that must contain number values (I already solved this by using the `_CellValidating` event, setting `e.Cancel = true` when the input is not a number)

The problem is when I click File>Save while cell is still dirty (in edit mode) it's value is ignored and not included in the database record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the beginning of the File>Save handler, call [`myDataGridView.EndEdit()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158620.aspx) to get out of edit mode and be able to get the value of the cell.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcelldirtystatechanged.aspx) if you want to immediately commit the cell changes to the underlying DataSource-

```
void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender,
    EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}
```

[MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcelldirtystatechanged.aspx)

A cell is marked as modified if its contents have changed but the change has not been saved.

This event typically occurs when a cell has been edited but the change has not been committed to the data cache, or when an edit operation is canceled.

Comment: You might want to avoid this if there is any validation on the cell content (e.g. the input must be numeric). Users won't be able to enter something invalid on the way to a valid entry - e.g. you wouldn't be able to enter 1.6e-19 because when you get to 1.6e it will fail validation.